# Only observer can ask all turtles - NetLogo error

Tags: netlogo

I am new user for Netlogo,
Although when I checked the code, there are no issues. However, when i run the program a while, it throws error message

> Only the observer can ASK the set of all turtles. Error while turtle 0 running ASK. called by procedure EXIT called by procedure Customer, GO and by button 'go'

```
to go
customer
end

to setup-turtles
create-turtles 1
ask turtles
[
set shape "person"
set size 3
set heading -90
fd 10
setxy 15 -15
set color red
]
end

to customer
ask turtles
[
set products ( products )
rt (random 360)
fd 1
if patch-here = one-of patches with
[
  pcolor = green
]
[
  set pcolor orange
  set products (products + 1)
]
if patch-here = one-of patches with
[
  pcolor = gray
]
[exit]
show count patches with
[pcolor = green ]


move-to one-of patches with
[
  pcolor = black
]

]
end



to exit
ask turtles
[
ifelse patch-here = one-of patches with
[
  pcolor = gray
]
[ifelse count products >= 2
  [
    die
  ]
  [move-to one-of patches with
    [
      pcolor = green or pcolor = black
    ]
  ]
]
  [
    die
  ]
move-to one-of patches with
  [pcolor = green
  ]

move-to one-of patches with
    [pcolor = black
    ]


  ]

end
```

Comment: I can't replicate the error with the code provided, as you may have omitted the code responsible for changing patch color. However, I'm about 99% sure that the problem stems from the fact that you have nested `ask` statements- the `ask turtles` in your `customer` procedure calls on the `exit` procedure, which contains another `ask turtles`. So, your turtles who try to `exit` are then asking all turtles to do this procedure- try dropping the entire `ask turtles` code block from your `exit` procedure and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Edited question format for ease of Read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your customer procedure, you have

```
ask turtles
[ ...
  if patch-here = one-of patches with [pcolor = gray]
  [ exit ]
  ...
]
```

So the exit procedure is being called by any turtle that is on a gray patch. Each turtle that meets that condition enters the exit procedure. As soon as it enters that procedure, the first command (in the exit procedure) is to `ask turtles`. So a turtle is asking all turtles to do something.

This is explicitly banned by the NetLogo language partly because it is a common source of beginner errors and is generally both unnecessary and inefficient. You have already selected the turtle to exit, what is it that *this particular turtle* needs to do to actually exit. It is very unlikely that they need to identify all the turtles on gray patches.